# Check if set is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Check if set is convex:
$$V = \{x \in \mathbb{R^n} : \lVert x\rVert = r \}$$

Obviously this set is non convex, but if there
is a method to show that numerically instead of
by logical thinking. I mean, in my class we prove
the set is convex by:
$$V = \{x \in \mathbb{R^n} : \lVert x\rVert \le r \}$$
$\lVert \theta x + (1 - \theta)y \rVert = \lVert \theta x \rVert + \lVert (1 - \theta)y \rVert =
\theta \lVert x \rVert + (1 - \theta) \lVert y \rVert \le \theta r + (1 - \theta)r = r$

which implies that V is convex. But why it does not hold for the first set?
$\lVert \theta x + (1 - \theta)y \rVert = \lVert \theta x \rVert + \lVert (1 - \theta)y \rVert =
\theta \lVert x \rVert + (1 - \theta) \lVert y \rVert = \theta r + (1 - \theta)r = r$

For me this looks valid, but for sure it should not. I know that if I find a subset that does not satisfy this inequality then it will be a proof that this set is non convex. But besides having intuiton that given set might non be convex
a then looking for some subset is there a way to check numerically without guessing that it might not be convex?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily see that points $[r,0,\dots,0]$ and $[-r,0,\dots,0]$ are in the set, but its average, which is $[0,0,\dots,0]$, is definitely not in the set. And that's it.

Comment: More generally, if $x$ is in the set, so is $-x$, but $\frac12x+\frac12(-x)=0$ is not.

Comment: True, got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because this statement:
$$\lVert \theta x + (1 - \theta)y \rVert = \lVert \theta x \rVert + \lVert (1 - \theta)y \rVert =
\theta \lVert x \rVert + (1 - \theta) \lVert y \rVert \le \theta r + (1 - \theta)r = r$$

is false. In particular, it is not true in general that $\lVert \theta x + (1 - \theta)y \rVert = \lVert \theta x \rVert + \lVert (1 - \theta)y \rVert$. Instead, all we can say is

$$\lVert \theta x + (1 - \theta)y \rVert \le \lVert \theta x \rVert + \lVert (1 - \theta)y \rVert$$

This is enough to prove the convexity of your second set, but not your first set.

Comment: great thanks! Completely forgot about it